# BigInteger modPow with BigDecimal exponent

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal, pow, modulo

I need a calculation of a BigInteger modPow, but with a BigDecimal as exponent.

Converting to double or using BigDecimal.pow and then mod is not possible in this case, since the full result without the mod will not fit into memory.
(and double lacks precision)
So converting to BigInteger with proper scale is out of question too.

I have found no library or similar for that.

Is it even mathematically possible to do an efficient modPow with a fractioned exponent without calculating the full exponentiation before?

EDIT:
Example

```
BigInteger base = BigInteger.valueOf("101");
BigDecimal exp = BigDecimal.valueOf("24.387207613444534);
BigInteger mod = BigInteger.valueOf("10403");

BigInteger result = base.modPow(exp, mod)
```

These sample numbers are very small, the intended use needs much bigger ones.
Its supposed to deliver the mod of a number that itself is too large to hold in RAM, but is log and an integer divisor are known.

Comment: *...calculation of a BigInteger modPow, but with a BigDecimal as exponent...* What does this even mean to you, mathematically? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/141193). By the most reasonable definition I can think of, this involves computing 10'th roots mod your modulus, and they may not even exist.

Comment: Can you give examples of inputs along with the expected outputs for those inputs? It's far from clear that what you're asking about is well-defined mathematically. What's this for? (BTW, you don't mention a language either. Java?)  To take one example, what would you want `modPow(5, 3.2, 7)` to produce, and why?

Comment: @MarkDickinson examples supplied. I´m java based, but that does not matter much. For your example i´d expect 4 as result, since 5^3.2 = 172,... mod 7 = 4

Comment: So you're throwing away the fractional part? That is, you want `integer_part_of(base ^ exponent) mod modulus`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson yes.

Answer (score 0):

So i found a way in the meantime.
base ^ (floor(exp - 1)) as regular modPow
multiplied with
base ^ (1+ (exp - floor(exp))
Then floor and mod.
The last exponentiation with factor 1.x is still small enough to fit into RAM.

Comment: This doesn't work. You don't get the same results this way as you would using `int(base ^ exponent) % modulus`. You can easily test with a few small examples to check this. Essentially, real numbers modulo a modulus don't have a nice arithmetic structure in the same way that integers modulo a modulus do.

Comment: yes you are right. It just coincidentally worked for the examples i used when i tried this approach.

Comment: Honestly, I agree with James Polk: this seems like an XY-problem. The operation you're describing is quite a peculiar one mathematically (unlike integer modpow, which is common and natural), and I'm skeptical that it's really the operation you want or need.